# jQuery MultiSelect Library Uses Incorrect Method to Handle "Select All"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I'm trying to update a large web application that uses [an extended version of Cory S.N. LaViska's jQuery.multiSelect plugin](https://github.com/rudionrails/jquery.multiSelect).

I updated to the latest code and it fixed a problem I was encountering. However, it introduced a new problem: Checking the Select All option now unchecks everything instead of checking it.

I'm not super advanced in JavaScript but have isolated the problem to the following code:

```
currentMultiSelect.next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT.selectAll').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == true)
        $(this).parent().parent().find('INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked', true).parent().addClass('checked');
    else
        $(this).parent().parent().find('INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked', false).parent().removeClass('checked');
});
```

The problem is that `$(this).attr('checked')` returns "checked". And so `$(this).attr('checked') == true` will always be false. And the code never detects that this option is, in fact, checked!

Okay, so I understand the problem. But why would it ever be written this way, and what is the most reliable way to fix this? I'd be interested to know how a JavaScript/jQuery expert would address this.

Comment: you are using very old version of multiselect. which jquery version you are using right now?

Comment: After spending considerable time looking, I haven't found a newer version of this particular flavor of a multiselect component. (I know there are other flavors.) I'm using jQuery 1.7.2.

Comment: If you are restricted to use this file then you have to change all your .attr('checked') to .prop('checked').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checked` is a property, you should use `prop` method, when a boolean attribute like `disabled` or `checked` is set to an element, the value is mapped to the relevant DOM property of the element(browser do this), as of `jQuery 1.6` for modifying properties, `prop` method should be used instead of `attr`.

So you code should looks like this

```
currentMultiSelect.next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT.selectAll').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).parent().parent().find('INPUT:checkbox').prop('checked', true).parent().addClass('checked');
    else
        $(this).parent().parent().find('INPUT:checkbox').prop('checked', false).parent().removeClass('checked');
});
```

Better if you use `.is(":checked")` for checking whether the checkbox is checked or not. But use `prop` to set the `checked property of checkbox`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `$(this).attr('checked') == true` which will return a string try `$(this).prop('checked') == true`

`$.prop()` will return `boolean true` when the element is checked or `boolean false` when it is not.

A little extra information on `$.attr()` is it returns the contents of the attribute. So if your html is:

```
<input id="elem" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Then `$('#elem').attr("checked")` is only going to return the string inside that attribute of the selected element.

If you really wanted to use `$.attr()` you could do this.

```
if ($(elem).attr("checked") != '') { ... }
```